# Custom field values in filter picker

Tags: 2010, 2013, filter, custom-field-types

Is there any way to modify logic which SharePoint use to display filter values? When there is custom field which inherit from SPFieldText, the filter values are taken directly from fieldValue... Example:

[image]

This fieldValue looks like taxonomy field value, however it is not used as taxonomy.

How to modify display to show only specified part of fieldValue? For example, without the guid.

I have added 2013 tag, because if it is possible to modify filter values in 2013 but not 2010, I am also interested.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - use javascript. Filter picker is shown in iframe, however elements that we need, they have nice css class, so simply use getElementsByClassName. If you need detailed explanation, please send me a message.